# What and how is the "Compare Densities" plot created in JMP under a one-way ANOVA?

Tags: anova, jmp

I recently performed a simple one-way ANOVA for a homework problem

[image]

For a second part of the problem we are asked to construct a plot to graphically compare the means at the factor levels, specifically like the one shown below

[image]

Though this is merely an example from the book. In this plot the mean at each level has a t-distribution constructed along the x-axis. This t-distribution is then scaled by the "best guess" at the population standard deviation $ \sqrt{MS_E / n}$.

I have tried to find a way to recreate this plot in JMP 13 for my given problem, and in this effort I stumbled upon the "Compare Densities" plot. This plot looks very close to that of the one described above, though, obviously there are differences.

[image]

I have found JMP notoriously difficult to search on Google, specifically what it is doing exactly. Thus, **what is this plot, how is it created, is it similar to the plot described above?**

Answer (score 1):

The [Compare Densities feature](https://www.jmp.com/support/help/14-2/densities.shtml) is showing independent kernel density smoothers for each group overlaid.

However, that's not at all the same as the Figure 3.11 from Montgomery's *Design and Analysis of Experiments*. The curves and arrows in that figure are meant to convey a single curve that is moved horizontally to find a place where it sufficiently covers the dots on the line below it, which represent the observed group means.

For general JMP help, there is a pretty active [JMP user community](https://community.jmp.com/).